# how to post to a form with jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code but when I submit the from the page redirects. I want to be able to post to it using jquery/ajax so that the page wont refresh on submit. Can someone show me a jsfiddle demo?

```
<form id="widget_contact" action="http://www.mysaintssearch.com/?cmd=sb-gimme&from=?cmd=home" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pcode" id="fc_name" />
<input type="hidden" name="hdnCmd" value="sb-gimme" />
<input name="send_button" id="fc_submit" class="btn_b" type="submit" value="Gimme" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck? There's a very clear example on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ we don't code for you, we help you code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You requested a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/CyMg4/)

**HTML**

I had to modify the action URL, otherwise it's XSS

```
<form id="widget_contact" action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pcode" id="fc_name" />
<input type="hidden" name="hdnCmd" value="sb-gimme" />
<input name="send_button" id="fc_submit" class="btn_b" type="submit" value="Gimme" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#widget_contact').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: form.prop('action'),
        method: form.prop('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(){
            alert('Hurraaaayyy');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i forgot to mention this form is on another website

Comment: You can not post to another domain. This would be [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). The only possibility would be to use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), but that is not cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the **[jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#widget_contact').submit(function(){ 

    $.post('http://www.mysaintssearch.com/?cmd=sb-gimme&from=?cmd=home', $('#widget_contact').serialize(), function(data) {
       // data is the variable that's returned from the form page

    });
return false; // so the page won't submit           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I don't use in my web sites:

form,
table,
input type submit,
input type button,
name in identifications unless it is a multiple choice item (like checkbox)

In this case here, specifically, my solution would be:

```
<div ....>
 <input type="text" id="fc_name" />
 <span id='hdnCmd' style='display:none; ' >sb-gimme</span>
 <span onClick='mySubmit(); ' >SUBMIT</span>
</div>

...
function mySubmit() {
    var myData = 'fc_name='+$('#fc_name').val();
        myData += '&hdnCmd='+$('#hdnCmd').text();
    $.post('processingPage.asp', myData, function (data) {
        ... display a returning success or failure
    });
}
```

Comment: This is terrible advice! You should use the HTML elements rather than some strange JavaScript replication of them. Firstly it's easier and secondly it degrades properly when JavaScript is turned off.