# JQuery $.ajax how to post data to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to post to a form with jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099875/how-to-post-to-a-form-with-jquery-ajax)

How can i post data to server via Jquery Ajax?

JQuery

```
function postNewBaseLine() {
    var id = "300";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetNewBaseVersion",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: id,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
}
```

cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetNewBaseVersion(string version)
{
    // I want it here!
}
```

I am using script manager

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true"
    runat="server" />
```

**EDIT:**
after changing to `data: { 'version': id },`

I am getting
POST _http://localhost:49852/ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetNewBaseVersion 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You should tag this with the proper server side technologies as well, apart from that your data element needs key/value pairs like `var id = {"amount":"300"}`

Comment: instead of `data: id,` try `data: {'id':id},`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the data object to something like:

```
function postNewBaseLine() {
    var id = "300";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetNewBaseVersion",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {version: id},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I am getting: POST http://localhost:49852/ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetNewBaseVersion 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: what does the debug tool say?

Answer (score 1):

First change ID to an object, i believe the quotes are important.

```
function postNewBaseLine() {
var id = "300";
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ManagerBaseKit.aspx/SetNewBaseVersion",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"version": id},
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success!');
        }
    });
```

}

You may also need to add some attributes to your service method

```
          [WebMethod]
          [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, bodystyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
            public static void SetNewBaseVersion(string version)
            {
                // I want it here!
            }
```