# how to print the id value of a form into the action with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that submits to the same page, but when the TITLE input changes and the form is submitted, the form is submitted to a page that no longer exists because the TITLE has been changed in the database.

my url is http://localhost/mvc1/content/show_item/title=home

where the form record to be pulled is the TITLE field in the database, so if I change the title to 'Homepage', the form is still submitted to .../title=home

my original action attribute was:
    action="http://localhost/mvc1/content/show_item/title=home; ?>"

which i changed to
    action="document.write(document.getElementById('TITLE').value);"

which works fine but only when it comes below the actual TITLE element

if I put the script at the end of the file then the value from the TITLE element appears, but not when I put the script in the action attribute

my form is as follows:

```
<form name="TABLE_CONTENT" method="POST" action="SCRIPT_DIDN'T_WORK_HERE">
<input type="hidden" name="FORM_NAME" value="TABLE_CONTENT" />
<input type="hidden" name="SUBMITTED" value="SUBMITTED" />
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="500">
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="ID">ID</label>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ID" value="{$ID}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="TITLE">TITLE</label>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="TITLE" id="TITLE" value="{$TITLE}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="CONTENT">CONTENT</label>:</td>
<td><textarea name="CONTENT">{$CONTENT}</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="URL">URL</label>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="URL" value="{$URL}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Edit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I'm sure this is actually a pretty common problem when a form submits to iteself, but I haven't been able to figure this one out, I'm assuming I need a javascript function with an onchange attribute on the title="Home" element but I have little experience with javascript and haven't been able to find anything that I can make work on my own, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please implement AJAX to submit your form, on such case page will not be reloaded so you will be on your same page.

And as the response of AJAX request processing get the required action url from database. And dynamically update your action url each time before submitting the request (from previous response of form submission).

Hope it might help you

Comment: view this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099875/how-to-post-to-a-form-with-jquery-ajax